# Filter Web Content with Drop down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm using a "PHP website" and i'm not being able to give to user a "drop down filter" to filter the content... In resume, i would like to give to user the same experience as in this website: https://www.hidglobal.com/products/rfid-tags/identification-technologies

If you change the options at the right side, on the Dropdown menus, the content will be filtered. Is exactly what i need to do in my website, but i'm not 100% familiar with javascript, so, if someone perhaps can help me... I'm searching on the web for more than 4days and all the answers that i find is always for tables, and this is not exactly a table, so, if someone peharps can help me, would be wonderfull!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Right click on the page, select "view source", and try to understand how it works, come up with some code, and we will help you when you're stuck. But no one will write a website for you for free I'm afraid!

Comment: It would help if you post your current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement this kind of dynamic web content the easiest way is to use a data-binding front-end library such as [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/). Of course you can always write your own js code for this but that just won't cut it. I suggest getting familiar with one of these libraries and use for example an ng-model binding with the select dropdowns to the right bound to the content you show on the left hand side (AngularJS).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i understand that no ones will come with a "free code" to me, that's not my intention...

I already take a look into their code, but as their website is giant, to me it's a little bit hard to understand it all, as i'm not a "Pro".

I would just like that someone tells the right way to approach the problem, and what should i search, don't know, something that helps me finding the solution...

Thanks.